# Regex starting with 5, excluding specific preceding numbers, and 6 characters in length

Tags: regex

I beseech thee, oh gods of the mighty RegEx... hear my plee!!!

I need a Regex for the following rules

1. -Number has to be 6 characters long
2. -Number has to start with 5
3. Number cannot start with "50****" or "589***"(It can start with 51, 52, 587, 583, etc...)

What I'm working off of right now is

`^5(?!(0\b|89\b))\d+\b.`

Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^5(?!(?:0|89))\d{5}$
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/1

You dont need `\b` after `0` or `89` as you dont expect a `word boundary` there.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!